# Show remaining months in year

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to show the remaining months of current year and remove the past months from current month in ionic angular or javascript. Here is my code:

```
month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
    'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

currentMonth = this.month[new Date().getMonth()];
```

Comment: what's the error, what have you tried? also, refrain from asking the question only in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slice

```js
const month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

const d = new Date();
const rest = month.slice(d.getMonth())

console.log(rest)
```